# Smart GWT HTML Layout

Tags: smartgwt

Hello All
I am using smart gwt 2.2, Operating system is Windows xp and browser is Mozilla Firefox.

Before working on the smart gwt I worked on smart gwt-ext.
In gwt-ext I used HTMLTable to give html view to my form. But after using HTMLTable I found TableLayout in gwt-ext, which is more easy to use and manage.
Because for putting element in HTMLTable I have to write complex for loop,
But the TableLayout is rich enough to handle this type of coding.

So I searched some type of Table Layout component in the smart gwt, But not succeeded yet.
So I just want to know that I have a form and for HTML preview Is there better way than HTML Table in smart gwt.

My form will be like this:
If there is 3 text fields then In the first column of the HTML Table will be Label
column on in the second column the control (i.e Text Field) will be putted.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello All
Chapter 6 "Layout" from the SmartGWT Quick Start Guide.There is Form Layout in the Smart GWT 
which also provide the method named RowSpan , ColSpan, NumOfColumns.
So Form Layout can be a substitute of Table Layout (in gwt-ext) in smart gwt.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the exact same question ([HTML Table-like Layout](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=10462)) on the SmartGWT forums and never got a reply.  I think we're stuck with HLayout, VLayout, HStack and VStack.  See Chapter 6 "Layout" from the [SmartGWT Quick Start Guide](http://www.smartclient.com/releases/SmartGWT_Quick_Start_Guide.pdf).

You could add HTML Layout to their [Wishlist](http://forums.smartclient.com/forumdisplay.php?f=5).